# Instance wise connection String

Tags: c#, connection-string, desktop-application

I am using a singleton approach where my C# class library accepts a connection string and stores it in a static variable and the variable in turn is used by different classes to perform specific tasks. The process is working fine until now, but I have a situation where a windows consumer application has to create N instances of the said class and each instance has to work with a different database simultaneously.

Obviously, the static approach will no longer work, therefore I removed the static variables. I just want to know, what is the best approach to follow other than passing the connection string from class to class? I also tried using the Properties.Settings.Default to store the connection string, but it overwrites the existing string every time a new instance is created!

**A prototype of my entire project (small though) is listed below:**

I have class ConnectionString, whose job is to accept and make connection string available to other classes in the namespace.

```
internal class ConnectionString
            {
                private string _connectionstring { get; set; }
                public ConnectionString(string connectionstring)
                {
                    _connectionstring = connectionstring;

                    //WHERE TO STORE THIS STRING FOR METHODS OF OTHER CLASSES TO CONSUME????

                }
            }
```

Then there is Operations class that performs certain operations on the database.

```
internal class Operations
            {
                public void Operation1()
                {

                    using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
                    {
                        //Some operation
                    }
                }

                public void Operation2()
                {
                    using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
                    {
                        //Some other operation
                    }

                }

                public void Operation3()
                {
                    using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
                    {
                        //Some other operation
                    }

                }      
            }
```

The Class exposed by the library that my windows app wants to consume is titled Base. This in turn would consume the above classes to perform the overall task.

```
public class Base
    {
        public Base(string connectionstring)
        {
            var ConnInstance = new ConnectionString(connectionstring);
            var OpInstance = new Operations();

            OpInstance.Operation1();
            OpInstance.Operation2();
            OpInstance.Operation3();

        }
    }
```

Finally, the consumer application needs to simultaneously create n instances of Base and pass a connection string to it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var ins1 = new Base("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DATABASE1; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                var ins2 = new Base("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DATABASE2; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                var ins3 = new Base("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DATABASE3; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                var ins4 = new Base("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DATABASE4; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                var ins5 = new Base("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DATABASE5; Integrated Security=SSPI;");

            }
        }
```

**Thank you** ***in advance for any kind of help.***

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just pass the connection string to `Operations` when you create that object in `Base`? Then it would have whatever connection string you passed into the base constructor and do the right thing? This feels so obvious that I'm sure there must be a reason this isn't possible...

Comment: Chris, The actual program is much larger and I have just specified a prototype of the actual program. Imagine I have 15 - 20 different classes similar to Operations class and I do not want to pass the connection string to each of these classes.

Comment: What's the reason for not passing the connection string to these classes? They need to know what connection string to use so you have to pass *something* to them to identify which connection they need - why not the connection string itself?

Comment: It is indeed possible and I have put that approach as the last resort. I feel of it as burden for each class to store the connection string and then pass it to other class and then to other and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your database access layer with associated "operations" should not need to be aware of UI/Form concerns. Similarly a UI Form should not have to implement a connection string or database connection cache.

I suggest you need an intermediate connection factory class that is responsible for connection string caching and optionally a factory that can arbitrate between connection requests from specific UI forms. Then you just need to engineer access to the factory class from form instances.

I wonder if you are creating too much indirection between your app logic and database connection creation. The most important design objective with database connections is that they are short lived with local scope i.e. follow the many using( var db = new Connection ) dispose examples. A .Net runtime will typically maintain a cache of db connections beyond your direct control and as a result database connections are not expensive to create but they are expensive to lease to a specific form instance over a multi-minute duration.

The Azure DocumentDb API changes conventional wisdom about db connection creation, my answer above assumes the questioner is using a class SQL database.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I think I have been able to achieve the separation of concerns. The bigger issue that I am facing is where to store the connection string for each instance without disturbing the other.